# You can only display 60 characters per line

Tags: c#

When running this program, my first line has 62 digits while the other lines only have 60. How can I place 2 spaces in front of the first line so each line of the array is no more then 60 characters? So basically it would look like ( with two spaces in the beginning)

```
  9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

```
    using System;

namespace BigFactorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static int MAX = 5000;
        //This is telling the program what to multiply.
        private static void mult(int[] x, int n)
        {
            int y = 0, i, m;

            for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
            {
                m = y + x[i] * n;
                x[i] = m % 10000;
                y = m / 10000;
            }
        }
        //This is telling the program how to calculate factorial of n.
        public static void Factorial(int[] a, int n)
        {
            a[0] = 1;
            for (int i = n; i > 1; i--)
            {
                mult(a, i);
            }
        }
        //This is displaing the factorial after the calculation.
        public static void Display(int[] a)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = MAX - 1; a[i] == 0; i--) ;

            Console.Write(a[i]);
            for (int j = i - 1, c = 1; j >= 0; j--, c++)
            {
                string s = "" + a[j];
                Console.Write(s.PadLeft(4, '0'));
                if (c % 15 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //Telling user to enter a number.
                Console.Write("Enter a number to factor or a negative number to quit: ");
                int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                //Quit function
                if (n < 0) break;
                int[] arr = new int[MAX];
                Factorial(arr, n);
                Display(arr);
            }
            //100000 is the max number it can calculate
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, you say _my first line has 62 digits while the other lines only have 60_ but in your example the first line has two characters **less** than the other two?

Comment: So I ran the program -  https://dotnetfiddle.net/seEZvQ - and I think this shows the problem?

Comment: I want it to look like the example. When you run the current code it displays 62 characters in the first line and then 60 in the rest. I need them all to have only 60

Comment: Perhaps you could also explain what you are trying to do in your `Display`? From what I can see, it can be done much simpler. Single letter variables looks super cool and scientific, but it's really bad for code visibility/understanding

Comment: I need to fill in leading zeros by printing character zeros if the digits in an element of the array contains leading zeros

Comment: OK, here's an idea. In `Display`, rather than writing the values to the console, build up a string that represents the final value - so using a string called `result`:  `result += a[i];` and `result += s.PadLeft(4, '0');`. This then gives you a string which contains the whole result, which you can then display however you like: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YssXnl

Comment: (I had no idea that multiple variables could be used in the initializer of a `for` loop, as well as being able to do [other really odd things](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for))

Answer (score 0):

You have already demonstrated that you know how to use String.PadLeft(), so cache the strings that you are writing in memory so you can inspect them rather than writing directly out to the console.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public static void Display(int[] a)
{
    int i = 0;

    // build the string in memory, so we can inspect the length of the lines
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.Append(a[i]);
    for (int j = i - 1, c = 1; j >= 0; j--, c++)
    {
        output.Append($"{a[j]}".PadLeft(4, '0'));
        if (c % 15 == 0)
            output.AppendLine();
    }

    // get the lines into an array so we can normalise the length,
    // although we know the length today, calculating it expresses the intent better
    var lines = output.ToString().Split(new string [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var maxLength = lines.Max(x => x.Length);

    // now write the output to the console
    foreach(var line in lines)
        Console.WriteLine(line.PadLeft(maxLength, ' '));
}
```

> It is not necessary to use StringBuilder like this, you could have used a `List<string>` and that would simplify the code further. It is however useful to identify that code written targeting the `Console` can easily be refactored to write to memory via `StringBuilder` as the syntax is very similar.
>
> > You could also have used a `StringWriter` instance called `Console` and the syntax would be identical... But that was a step too far for a logic block as simple as this.